# How to count the number of spaces in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I need to write a program in which the output will be the number of sentences and average number of words. The code is working perfectly for counting the sentences, but for the second task, it doesn't work. I'm using branch if equal with the current char and the register in which I've declared the ascii value for space which is 32. With this code, the output for the average words is the total number of characters from the whole input. I can't understand how it can count every character when the beq is clearly incorrect. (I've also tried with *emptySpace: .asciiz " "*, but it's not working)

This is what I got so far:

```
.data
str_input: .space 256
dot: .asciiz  "."
msg1: .asciiz "Number of sentences: "
msg2: .asciiz "\nAverage number of words: "

.text
li $v0, 8       #read string
la $a0, str_input   #address of str_input vo $a0
li $a1, 256     #256 max
la $a2, dot
lb $a2, 0($a2)      
li $a3, 32
syscall
addi $t4, $zero, 0  #counter for words
addi $t5, $zero, 0  #counter for sentences

or $t0, $a0, $zero  #$t0 pointer to array 

start: 
lb $t1, 0($t0)      #$t1 current char
beqz $t1, end
jal check
addiu $t0, $t0, 1
j start

chech:
beq $t1, $a2, IsDot
beq $t1, $a3, IsEmptySpace

IsDot:
addi $t5, $t5, 1
jr $ra

IsEmptySpace:
addi $t4, $t4, 1
jr $ra

end: 
la $a0, msg1        #address of msg1 in $a0
li $v0, 4       #load string in $v0
syscall

add $a0, $t5, $zero
li $v0, 1
syscall         #print number of sentences

addi $t4, $t4, 1    #add the last word
div $t4, $t5        #divide number of words with number of sentences
mflo $t6

la $a0, msg2        #address of msg2
li $v0, 4       #load string in $v0
syscall

add $a0, $t6, $zero
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Comment: What do you want `chech`/`check` to do when it isn't a dot or space?  What do you see when you single step each instruction?

Comment: @ErikEidt `check` should only see whether the current character is dot or space, and if it's neither I want it to return to the main function `start` and move to the next character.

Comment: Ok, so what are you going to change to make it do that?

Comment: @ErikEidt I fixed it by adding `jr $ra` in the check function. Thank you.